PyTorch Gradient Computation Fails When Not Using Entire Input Tensor
I have a model that takes an input tensor , along with other inputs k and D. The model outputs several tensors, including cs_hat. When I compute gradients of cs_hat with respect to the first slice of inputs (inputs[:,:,0]), the gradient computation only succeeds if I compute it with respect to the entire tensor inputs instead of just the slice.
Here is a simplified version of my code that illustrates the problem:
import torch
from torch import nn

class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size = 3 , ffn_size = 15, ffn_layers = 2, res_block_size = 15, res_block_layers = 2):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        self.input_size = input_size
        self.activation = nn.LeakyReLU()

        self.ffn_size = ffn_size
        self.ffn_layers = ffn_layers
        self.res_block_size = res_block_size
        self.res_block_layers = res_block_layers

        self.linear_block_0 = self._make_linear_block(self.ffn_size, self.ffn_layers, input_size=self.input_size)

        self.final_layer_a = nn.Linear(self.res_block_size, 1, bias=False)
        self.final_layer_b = nn.Linear(self.res_block_size, 1, bias=False)
        self.final_layer_c = nn.Linear(self.res_block_size, 1, bias=False)
        self.final_layer_d = nn.Linear(self.res_block_size, 1, bias=False)




    def _make_linear_block(self, width, depth, input_size = None):

        if input_size is None:
            linear_block = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(width , width), self.activation])
        else:
            linear_block = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(input_size , width), self.activation])

        for _ in range(depth - 1):
            linear_block.append(nn.Linear(width, width))
            linear_block.append(self.activation)

        linear_block_ = nn.Sequential(*linear_block)

        return linear_block_


    def forward(self, inputs,k,D):

        t = inputs[:,:,0]
        x = inputs[:,:,1]

        input_t = torch.cat([t,k.view(-1,1),D.view(-1,1)],dim = -1)

        z0 = self.linear_block_0(input_t)

        a = self.final_layer_a(z0)
        b = self.final_layer_b(z0)
        c = self.final_layer_c(z0)
        d = self.final_layer_d(z0)

        return a,b,c,d


#Main

model = MyModel()

inputs = torch.tensor([[[0.4521, 0.5205]], [[0.3066, 0.6816]], [[0.0547, 0.9297]], [[0.3936, 0.9229]]], requires_grad=True) #supposed to be of size (batch_size,1 ,1)

batch_size = 4

k = torch.randn(batch_size, requires_grad=True)
D = torch.randn(batch_size, requires_grad=True)

# Forward pass
outputs = model(inputs, k, D)
cs_hat = outputs[2]  # Assuming cs_hat is the third output

# Gradient computation that works
cs_dt = torch.autograd.grad(cs_hat, inputs, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(cs_hat), create_graph=True)[0]
# Gradient computation that fails
cs_dt = torch.autograd.grad(cs_hat, inputs[:,:,0], grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(cs_hat), create_graph=True)[0]

My error message:
RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior.
Ensuring requires_grad=True is set before any operations.
Using torch.ones_like(cs_a_hat) to match the shape of grad_outputs.
Checking that t actually influences cs_hat (it does).
Setting allow_unused=True just gives me a None result (even though t influences cs_hat).
Tried the same with f(inputs)=2*inputs instead of passing to neural network. Same error
Questions:
Why does excluding parts of the input tensor from the gradient calculation cause this issue?
How can I correctly compute gradients with respect to only the needed parts of the input tensor without encountering this error?
If I accept that I need to use the whole input, will this add a lot computational complexity?

it comes from the fact that inputs[:,:,0] returns a copy of the data, making inputs[:,:,0] unseen by the graph as opposed to inputs. It is impossible to compute gradients on unseen data (how could you know "the influence" of the two elements of inputs on the scalar value in cs_hat[:, 0] without knowing the intermediate operations?).
What you want to achieve is totally possible, and without much overhead (I don't know how torch computes gradients but I assume it is darn efficient). You can do:
cs_hat = outputs[2]
cs_dt = torch.autograd.grad(cs_hat, inputs, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(cs_hat), create_graph=True)[0]
cs_dt[:, :, 0]  # gradient with respect to inputs[:, :, 0]


Shouldn't slicing generally keep the gradients though?

I'm sorry, I don't know how the graph knows that it has not seen the tensor before. As a further example torch.autograd.grad(cs_hat, inputs.clone(), grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(cs_hat), create_graph=True)[0] will return None too
